# Allow External Users Access (via AD external trusts)

Tags: permissions

Im new to SharePoint, and trying to figure out how to allow users from a external domain access to the sharepoint site.

I already have a AD external trust setup (Users from `DomainB` have access to folders located on `DomainA`).

However when I go into `Permissions > "Home members"` and search `DomainB\domain users` it cannot see the domain.

What am I doing wrong?
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Check this link http://www.boostsolutions.com/blog/how-to-add-trust-domains-in-a-sharepoint-farm/
The process quite straightforward but includes a lot of steps, may be you missed some of them.

Comment: Hey, thats the document I followed ;) I guess the bit that says "The key moment is connecting, check whether you can add one user of the trusted domain to one site collection which enable windows authentication." I dont where to find this part? im using sharepoint 2013

Comment: We haven't expirienced such problem. What type of trust you have configured - one-way or 2-way? Try take a look here http://blog.eastridge.net/sharepoint-people-picker-configuration-for-trusted-domain-users